# display: none removes whole div

Tags: html, css, display

```css
@media (max-width: 500px){
    .about-content {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }


    .cardcontent {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }

    .footer-links {
        float: left;
    }
    
    .brand-title {
        display: initial;
    }

    .toggle-button {
        display: flex;
    }

    .navbar-links { 
        width: 100%;
    }

    .navbar {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
        display: flex;
    }

    .navbar-links ul {
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .navbar-links li {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .navbar-link li a {
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    }

    .navbar-links.active{
        display: flex;
    }

    .banner-text{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<header> 
        <nav class="navbar"> <!-- Element for Website Navigation-->
          <div class="brand-title">RAZA</div>
          <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
          </a>
          <div class="navbar-links">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="about me.html">About Me</a></li>
              <li><a href="index.html">Portfolio</a></li>
              <li><a href="src/Resume.pdf" target="_blank">Resume</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="banner">
          <img src="src/Banner Image.svg" class="banner-img rellax" data-rellax-speed="10">
          <div class="banner-text rellax" data-rellax-speed="2">
            <h1>RAZA</h1>
            <h2 style="
            font-size: 1.85rem;">Shabih-ul-Hassan</h2>
            <h4 style="
            font-weight: bold">Graphic Designer & Video Editor</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
```

So I'm building a portfolio website on html & css. I want the banner to disappear after the screen width is reduced to a certain size.

Problem is when I remove the banner with `display: none`, it takes the full parent with it which includes the nav bar.

It works fine when I use `visibility: hidden` but it leaves this vapid empty space.

Comment: share the example code to better understand

Comment: Sure. Sorry about that. Never used Stack overflow before. I hope this will be enough

Comment: You're setting `.navbar-links` display to none in your css so that is making part of the navbar disappear along with the div with the class `.banner-text`

Comment: Removed and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .banner{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Dear! Somehow the CSS  isn't correctly coded. Remove everything from the styles that you have and add the above media query. For instance, this query will work for the mobile devices and banner will remove when switched to the mobile screens.  I hope it will work for you :)

[image]
[image]

Comment: So I should create the media queries from scratch?

Comment: Also still doesn't work. Sorry.

Comment: Strange ! this is working on my end. When you switch to mobile, banner removes and only left with navbar.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to answer the question. Just had to turn a position: relative to an absolute.
How that works? No idea. But hey, still learning